# Xamarin - Unable to add reference to PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

I'm new to Xamarin, so sorry if this question is a bit ignorant.

I created an Android project in VS2015, added a Class Library for android and added a UWP project. When I try to add the PCL reference to my UWP I get an error 'Unable to add a reference to the project foobar.PCL'

When I add a Windows Universal Class Library I can't add that reference to Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind I fixed it by creating a Portable Class Library that targets Windows Universal and Android

Comment: @am, click on the accept answer button, then it will be useful